# Why doesn't a lock-in measure the full voltage from a function generator? (3$omega$ setup)

Tags: measurements, experimental-technique, experimental-technology

I'm trying to build a setup for the 3$\omega$ technique, and the equipment is making my brain hurt.
When I send a signal directly from the function generator to the lock-in, it only measures about 71% of the input
[image]
However, the lock-in accurately reads the voltage from its own sine-out, and the amplitude of the output from the function generator was checked on an oscilloscope. I am baffled as to what is happening here.

It also reads 0 voltage on the third harmonic, which I'm not sure is supposed to happen either.
If anyone has done 3$\omega$ experiments before and could advise me on how to get this set up correctly it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you upload the oscilloscope measurement?

Comment: What quadrature are you measuring? How did you set the phase? Does the $3\omega$ signal show up in a spectrum analyzer (or a Fourier transform of your oscilloscope data)?

Comment: $0.71\approx 1/\sqrt{2}$. I think this is significant. Could one of your machines be working with root-mean-square values, and another with full amplitude?

Comment: @Cryo, good observation! I'm almost certain that this is it! (I can't upvote comments yet, but I can accept it if you post as an answer).
Gilbert and Eranreches, I have no way of connecting the lab oscilloscope to a computer yet, but I'll work on it.

Comment: Glad if it helps. Knowledge seared into memory by painful experience :-)